# Inner text shadow, blue background, white color?

Tags: css, shadow

I have a blue box with box shadow and text color is white, like this: 
[image: screenshot].

Is it possible, to add an inner shadow?
Like [this](https://jsfiddle.net/NeqCC/4822/) (jsfiddle)? It will not work with text color white, like my example.

```css
body {
  /* This has to be same as the text-shadows below */
  background: #def;
}

h1 {
  font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 6em;
  line-height: 1em;
}

.inset-text {
  /* Shadows are visible under slightly transparent text color */
  color: rgba(10, 60, 150, 0.8);
  text-shadow: 1px 4px 6px #def, 0 0 0 #000, 1px 4px 6px #def;
}


/* Don't show shadows when selecting text */

::-moz-selection {
  background: #5af;
  color: #fff;
  text-shadow: none;
}

::selection {
  background: #5af;
  color: #fff;
  text-shadow: none;
}
```

```html
<h1 class="inset-text">Inset text-shadow trick</h1>
```

Comment: are you looking for shadowing the text or the box which holds it?

Comment: shadowing in the text (inner shadow, not outside text). Plus shadow outside box (but this isn't a problem).

The blue background should be #277ac0, not lightblue like in jsfiddle example.

Comment: What I want and what I get: http://imgur.com/a/q10rB

Answer (score 0):

Can you please check if it is your requirement or not?

```
body {
    /* This has to be same as the text-shadows below */
    background: #006db1;
}
h1 {
    font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 6em;
    line-height: 1em;
}
.inset-text {
    /* Shadows are visible under slightly transparent text color */
    color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);
    text-shadow: 1px 4px 6px #555, 0 0 0 #ddd, 1px 4px 6px #000;
}
/* Don't show shadows when selecting text */
::-moz-selection { background: #fff; color: #000; text-shadow: none; }
::selection { background: #fff; color: #000; text-shadow: none; }
```

Comment: Thanks, but no, there should only be a inner shadow, no outside text....

Answer (score 0):

In yuor demo, if you want `innerShaow` for your white color text.
 just set `color: rgba(255,255,255, 0.8);` then you can see the inner shadow.

```css
body {
    /* This has to be same as the text-shadows below */
    background: #277ac0;
}
h1 {
    font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 6em;
    line-height: 1em;
}
.inset-text {
    background-color: #565656;
    color: transparent;
    text-shadow: 0px 2px 3px rgba(255,255,255,1);
    -webkit-background-clip: text;
    -moz-background-clip: text;
    background-clip: text;
}
/* Don't show shadows when selecting text */

::-moz-selection {
  background: #5af;
  color: #fff;
  text-shadow: none;
}

::selection {
  background: #5af;
  color: #fff;
  text-shadow: none;
}
```

```html
<h1 class="inset-text">Inset text-shadow trick</h1>
```

Comment: Sorry, in this Demo (not from me), was the wrong background, I need the background from my screenshot, it's darker: #277ac0 - and then there is only a gray color in text, no shadow.

Comment: @kalterwind I'm not sure what is your `inner shadow` looks like? could you provide me a sample??

Comment: @kalterwind ok I just make a bit change you can try it.

Comment: Thanks, but this looks like a blur-effect, not an inner shadow.